# Why is nothing appearing on my NEX 5n LCD screen?

Tags: troubleshooting, sony-nex, display, rear-lcd

Nothing appears on my NEX 5N LCD screen. Camera can be turned on and pictures taken using the view finder, but LCD screen is blank.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: Did it suddenly stop working? Had you changed any settings? Have you tried resetting the camera?  Battery fully charged?

Comment: Specifically, did you set the display off? Is there an issue with the face-detection mechanism in the viewfinder (I believe it detects IR when you move camera to face, shutting the back LCD screen).

Comment: I was taking photos of my son while it was suddenly disappear. I nothing changed any setting after attaching the view finder, I could continued. Today I insert the battery and turned camera on LED display was working for 2-3 second again nothing appears.

Comment: Could you imagine what's wrong with this camera?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Some cameras from some manufacturers are not known for durability. Best to send it in for repairs. Who knows they might even fix it for free.